# PolynomialZeros package in Julia

Tags: julia, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I was trying to use the Package 'PolynomialZeros' to solve for the roots of a polynomial. However, I got these errors when using it. Any help with this? Thanks~
[image]

Comment: seems like currently precompiling is not enabled in one of its dependencies, I believe you could start Julia with  `julia --precompiled=no  --compilecache=no` to work around this.

Comment: @Gnimuc Thank you very much for replying! I am just a new starter with Julia, could you please be more specific about this? Thank you!

Comment: the problem here is how to add those flags when starting julia in Jupyter, which I also don't know, that's why I didn't write an anwser. My guess is we need to add those flags somewhere in the jupyter specs.

Comment: It's worth trying just restarting the session and including it again. It can be the package caches are in a weird state. The package loads without problems on my system.

Comment: @MichaelK.Borregaard If it's not a dependency precompiling problem,  then  the cache problem can be fixed by deleting the `PolynomialZeros.ji` in `.julia\lib\v0.6\. ` It's equivalent to start a julia session with `--compilecache=no`.  just restarting the session might not help ;)

Comment: Yes, that's the next step. Restarting usually works for me though :-)

Comment: But on second thought that's probably because I most often create the problem for myself by removing precompilation from some packages...